# css3 transition when using toggleClass with jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

guys.

I'm trying to make a collapsible content with jQuery. I "almost" did it, but the problem are the transitions. The collapse has been applying instantly, without the transitions.

ps: I tried other elements, as toggle, add/removeClass, hide/show... Any of these worked.

Above is my complete code in pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/gw6Zm3Ey

Comment: You can't animate `height` having the value `auto`, also, the `transition` property is missing which property to transist, as in `transition: height 0.75s linear`

Comment: @LGSon I think if you omit the property value of `transition` it will default to `all`, so technically its not required, but is recommended.

Comment: @zgood And using `all` is not recommended either, as one easily get unexpected result based on which values each browser decides to animate

Comment: @LGSon I know thats why I ended my comment with _but is recommended_ ... I was just making the point that its not required is all

Comment: @zgood Perfect...so now we covered all of it :)

Comment: In the future, please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot animate to `height:auto;` you would need to set a static height to transition to (you also would need to remove `overflow: visible;`, or ese everything becomes visible as soon as that class is applied - you can't animate overflow).

Here is a [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcqpkc0e/)

To solve this problem, people normally use jquery's `slideToggle()` which will dynamically get the height then animate it. I would look into that